# How to start gunicorn on startup EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, gunicorn, systemd

I am trying to run gunicorn on startup inside my EC2 instance, I've created a `myproject.service` file in `/lib/systemd/system/` that looks like this.

```
[Unit]
Description="my startup file"

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myproject
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To test if it is working I have been running these commands

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl start myproject`

`sudo systemctl status myproject`

this returns the error

```
Apr 02 09:14:13 ip-172-31-32-45 gunicorn[5827]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
Apr 02 09:14:13 ip-172-31-32-45 gunicorn[5827]:     from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
Apr 02 09:14:13 ip-172-31-32-45 gunicorn[5827]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
Apr 02 09:14:13 ip-172-31-32-45 systemd[1]: myproject.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 02 09:14:13 ip-172-31-32-45 systemd[1]: myproject.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've used `which gunicorn` to return the absolute path so I don't understand why gunicorn isn't found

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a virtual environment and everything worked great then, this ended up being my service file inside `/lib/systemd/system`

```
# myproject.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myproject
Type=simple
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/myproject/venv36/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myproject/venv36/bin/gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:application --daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```